# Xamarin set Cookies in Multiplatform iOS app using (Hybrid)WebView

Tags: ios, xamarin, cookies

I followed example from here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#invoke-c-from-javascript) to setup WebView for my project and I can invoke C# code from WebView page event, that is working fine.
However, before sending a request I have to setup a Cookie and that cookie should be passed to remote server. I followed several examples from net I am getting it to work for **Android** but **iOS** its not working.

Code I got from another Stackoverflow question as follows.

**Android** *Working*

```
var cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
cookieManager.SetAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie();
var cookies = UserInfo.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new System.Uri(AppInfo.URL_BASE));
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.Count; i++)
{
    string cookieValue = cookies[i].Value;
    string cookieDomain = cookies[i].Domain;
    string cookieName = cookies[i].Name;
    cookieManager.SetCookie(cookieDomain, cookieName + "=" + cookieValue);
}
```

**iOS** *Not Working*

```
// Set cookies here
var cookieUrl = new Uri(AppInfo.URL_BASE);
var cookieJar = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
cookieJar.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;
foreach (var aCookie in cookieJar.Cookies)
{
    cookieJar.DeleteCookie(aCookie);
}

var jCookies = UserInfo.CookieContainer.GetCookies(cookieUrl);
IList<NSHttpCookie> eCookies = 
                   (from object jCookie in jCookies 
                    where jCookie != null 
                    select (Cookie) jCookie 
                    into netCookie select new NSHttpCookie(netCookie)).ToList();
cookieJar.SetCookies(eCookies.ToArray(), cookieUrl, cookieUrl);
```

I have tried code from WebView documentation here, Cookie section (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#cookies)

I'll really appreciate if anybody can point out what I am doing wrong any hints.
Thanks.

**Update**

In my *HybridWebViewRenderer* method I am adding my custom Cookie as follows.

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
 {

    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        userController.RemoveAllUserScripts();
        userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler("invokeAction");
        HybridWebView hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
        hybridWebView.Cleanup();
    }

    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        string cookieDomain = new System.Uri(((HybridWebView)Element).Uri).Host;

        foreach (var c in NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cookie (Delete)" + c.Name);
            NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.DeleteCookie(c);
        }
            

        var cookieDict = new NSMutableDictionary();
        cookieDict.Add(NSHttpCookie.KeyDomain, new NSString("." + cookieDomain));
        cookieDict.Add(NSHttpCookie.KeyName, new NSString("ABC"));
        cookieDict.Add(NSHttpCookie.KeyValue, new NSString("123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426652340003"));
        cookieDict.Add(NSHttpCookie.KeyPath, new NSString("/"));
        cookieDict.Add(NSHttpCookie.KeyExpires, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToNSDate());

        var myCookie = new NSHttpCookie(cookieDict);

        NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.SetCookie(myCookie);

        string filename = $"{hybridView.Uri}";

        var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(filename));

        var wkNavigation = LoadRequest(request);
    }
 }
```

In **AppDelegate** I have added.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

Still no luck :( .........

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cookie in the shared storage.

Set your shared storage policy to always accept your own cookies.

In your ApplicationDelegate:

```
NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;
```

Comment: @wen-xu-li-msft updated code in question, AppDelegate thing still not working

Comment: You can try to implement the decisionHandler method.
For more information, please refer to the official documentation(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455643-webview?language=objc
) and conversion method(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/096ea31f-c474-4048-9703-8602c5828a34/need-help-in-converting-wknavigationresponse-decisionhandler-to-c?forum=xamarinios
).